# Calculating the jacobian matrix for a time-dependent system

Tags: numerical-methods, jacobian

For testing purposes I would like to calculate the Jacobian matrix of the time-dependent heat equation, i.e. 
$$\partial_tu=\nabla^2u+f$$
As far as I understood, the Jacobian can be calculated using 
$$F(u)=\partial_tu-\nabla^2u-f$$
and (with $\delta u$ a small step)
$$\begin{split}F'(u)(\delta u)&=\lim\limits_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{F(u+h\delta u)-F(u)}{h}\\
&=\lim\limits_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{\partial_t(u+h\delta u)-\nabla^2(u+h\delta u)-f-\partial_tu+\nabla^2u+f}{h}\\
&=\lim\limits_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{h\partial_t(\delta u)-h\nabla^2(\delta u)}{h}\\
&=\partial_t(\delta u)-\nabla^2(\delta u)\forall h\neq0\end{split}$$
That result can be rewritten into
$$F'(u)(\delta u)=\frac{\delta u_1-\delta u_0}{dt}-\nabla^2(\delta u)$$
Is that correct? If yes, what would $\delta u_1$ and $\delta u_0$ be? Or is there a mistake in the last step?

Comment: Why do you have $\delta u_0$? The first term should be $\partial_t(\delta u)$.

Comment: I intended to use the approximation $\partial_tu=\frac{u_1-u_0}{dt}$, if that is possible here?

Comment: If you want, you can write it as $\frac{\partial \delta u}{\partial t}$. What are meanings of $u_1$ and $u_0$?

Comment: When comparing it to the usual approach for time-dependent systems, $u_1$ is the new solution, and $u_0$ the old/current solution. But I do not know if that applies here, too.

Comment: What are the old/current solutions? I doubt that they can be used here.